# Script to List all Desktop and Laptop Model for Server 2008 Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, scripting

Is there any way I can list all the desktop and laptop model? There is no naming convention and I'm having difficulty differentiating laptop and desktop in our environment.

I have already tried to use `wmic` but in only one laptop.

```
c:\>wmic computersystem get model,name,manufacturer,systemtype
Manufacturer  Model    Name        SystemType
LENOVO        2236EG1  WINCMD-PC  x64-based PC
```

Need to run in a Domain Environment.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this, using PowerShell. Note that depending on the size of your domain, this may hit your domain controller pretty hard; I'd highly suggest you put some sort of filter other than "*" on the "Get-ADComputer" at the top

```
$allComputer = Get-ADComputer -Filter "*"
foreach ($c in $allComputer) {
  $wmi = Get-WmiObject -Computer $c.Name -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
  Write-Output "$($c.Name) - $($wmi.Manufacturer) $($wmi.Model) $($wmi.Name) $($wmi.SystemType)"
}
```

Comment: Hello DarkMoon, thank you for your response, will try this after i upgrade the domain controller to 2012. right now we are using server 2008, thats why i cant use powershell with active directory module.

Comment: Why not? I thought 2008 and up supported the AD cmdlets (on my mobile atm so I can't check easily), but if they don't, use the Quest (Dell) AD cmdlets like everyone else. :-P You just need to import the module first, then use Get-QADComputer instead of Get-ADComputer; I believe the parameters are the same. I can try to check that later when I'm on my PC.